# Are (bool)(i & 1) and i % 2 == 1 same?

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform

Are `(bool)(i & 1)` and `i % 2 == 1` always same where `i` is `int`?

Note: saying always I mean for all platforms (even when a byte is 16 bit) and for all standards of C and C++.

**Edit:**

For all standards of C and C++ where `bool` exist.

Comment: `bool` is not pre-defined in C. You need to `#include <stdbool.h>` which typedefs it to `_Bool` (`_Bool` is part of the C99 language)

Comment: @pmg: right, but if someone asks a question about `printf`, I don't say, "`printf` is not pre-defined in C. You need to `#include <stdio.h>`". Talking about bool in "all standards of C" is misguided, though, since it isn't in C89 in any form :-)

Comment: Right: that's what I meant --- `bool` is not pre-defined in all standards of C :)

Comment: Better use `i % 2 != 0` to test for odd numbers.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

No.

1s' complement representation of `int`, the representation of -1 is `1 ... 10`, so they differ.

Anyway, `i % 2` can be negative for negative `i` (indeed it's required to be in C99 when it's not 0), and hence not equal to 1 for negative odd numbers.

Comment: Are you sure? I think that the compiler handles this difference.

Comment: +1: This is the correct answer.  (You've identified both reasons that they can differ!)

Comment: @Kiril: bitwise operators work on the bit representation of the value. If `-1 & 1` is 1, then the C implementation isn't using 1s' complement, regardless of what the underlying hardware thinks on the subject. It's emulating 2s' complement or sign-magnitude.

Comment: What compiler handles depends on it's options and compiler itself.

Comment: @Steve Jessop - then, as `>>` and `<<` are bitwise operators too, are they unsafe? I can't believe that O.O

Comment: @Kiril: `<<` and `>>` have quite restricted definition for signed types - using `<<` with a negative LHS is undefined behavior. Using `>>` with a negative LHS is implementation-defined result. So yes, they are unsafe. 6.5.7/4 and /5 in C99.

Comment: @Mihran: yes, for non-negative values of `i` they are guaranteed to be equivalent, although as pmg says you need `bool` to exist.

Comment: @Steve - Ah, yes, I mean non-negative values (for `>>` and `<<` ). So, you mean, that if I need to parse a header (for received data from a socket, for example) and the header is >1B, I can't just check with `&` for some concrete bit, but I also need to check the complement and then use `&`? I'm shocked.

Comment: @Kiril: Shocking or not, C and C++ permit three different representations of signed integers, and always have done. I don't understand what you mean by your ">1B" header example. A header size necessarily is non-negative, so I don't see the problem unless you think you might be overflowing a signed integer type. That overflow is also not portable, never mind whether you try to use `&` on the result or not. So it's no good checking the complement, since if that happens you've already lost.

Comment: Code that uses bitwise ops on signed types is pretty much broken anyway, unless it's for reasons of ferocious optimization that therefore are totally implementation-specific and so you don't need it to be portable. Use unsigned types for bitwise things, or at least require the values to be non-negative, then you know exactly what the representation is. That said, anything other than 2's complement is extremely rare, so documenting your code "portable only to 2's complement implementations" is not likely to inconvenience your users.

Comment: Performance will be very different with some (many) compilers. @Steve Jessop - checking the 1-bit for even/odd is just fine with negative numbers (assuming 2's complement) and is hardly a "ferocious optimization". It also never returns negative numbers, and I bet is more readable to most programmers.

Comment: @phkahler: on my compiler (gcc) and architecture (x86), `i % 2 != 0` emits identical code to `i &1`, so my sympathies if your compiler is worse. Working around that kind of quality-of-implementation issue is fairly annoying optimization, if not exactly "ferocious". As for readability, either of us can claim without evidence which one of those better expresses the property of being odd. As a mathematician by training obviously I think the `%` does.

Comment: @Steve - sorry, I confused, a little. I mixed 1/2 complement with big/little indian representation. By ">1B" I meant header, that contains, for example, 4B int. Anyway, never mind, my bad.

Comment: @Steve - your one compiler and architecture is hardly "evidence" for a question that specifically states "all platforms (even when a byte is 16 bit) and for all standards of C and C++". "ferocious" was your term. But I do get the math bias given your math background :-)

Comment: @phkahler: yes, I was unclear about two different differences. I took the question ("are they the same") to be, "do they have the same meaning". Separately, they might have different performance as you point out, but I didn't consider that at all when I answered the question. Once the 2's complement restriction (and changing `==1` to `!=0`) grants them the same meaning: since my preferred implementation successfully optimizes both to the same thing, I consider it annoying to have to to hand-optimize, but since it's an easy optimization to make I'm backing off my term "ferocious" to "annoying".

Comment: Does that make sense? It's not that I think my one example "proves" performance is identical everywhere, it's that I think my one example justifies me being very grumpy about having to decide between them on the basis of optimizing for some other, inferior-in-this-respect implementation.

Answer (score 9):

No.

For example, try it if i is -1. `-1 % 2 == -1`, and `(bool) (-1 & 1)` is 1.

(Assuming 2-complement)