# Integer evenness testing (% 2 vs & 1)

Tags: c

Do these two statements compile equivalently: n % 2 == 0 and n & 1 == 0 ?

if not, is one more efficient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they do not always give the same result.  The C standard allows for ones' complement implementations, in which case they will give a different result for negative `n`.

Answer (score 5):

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438402/are-booli-1-and-i-2-1-same) was asked yesterday.

`i % 2` and `i & 1` are not the same:

- If your integer is not unsigned, depending on its representation, `n & 1` does not necessarily indicate whether your integer is even or odd.
- `i % 2` can be negative.

For unsigned integers, a good compiler should reasonably produce equally efficient code.

Comment: Look at that :) That point was the one I was trying to make in my answer and comment - but not as clear as it's made here :)

Comment: if i can be negative you just call abs before using %2

Comment: And if you want to test for even numbers then `i % 2 == 0` is correct for negative `i`

Comment: i & 1 is correct for two's-complement implementations (which is basically everything out there).

Answer (score 3):

That depends on your compiler.

An optimizing compiler on an x86 architecture might translate `n % 2` into `n & 1`, since they're equivalient for 2s complement integers. A different compiler on the same platform, or the same compiler on a different platform, might give you other results.

My suggestion is to use `n % 2`, since that's what you're trying to accomplish in mathematical terms, and profile your application before you start micro-optimizing.

Answer (score 2):

Irrespective of which one is faster, and it's unlikely that it would ever matter, `n % 2 == 0` is to be preferred because it makes your intent clear. Prefer it for the same reason that you prefer writing `*2` to bit shifts.

Comment: Plus smart compilers will figure such simple optimizations out.

Comment: @space true but I'd still use the clearer coding even if the compiler couldn't figure out the optimisation

Answer (score 1):

They won't compile equivalently. (Actually I should say depends on compiler. But safer to assume that compilation will be different).
(n & 1) is efficient. (Again. not sure about endian stuff, will check and let you know.)
Ok- Checked on endian stuff. It matters with the order of bytes and not the order of bits. So (n & 1) must be platform independent.

Comment: Endianess won't come into it. Different integer representations do - one's complement negative numbers are not `(n & 1)` if they're uneven.

Comment: @gnud :- Thanks mate. I took time to figure that out. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an arbitrary precision integer library in C++ once.  both % and & were overloaded such that they did what you'd expect just on really big ints.  Arbitrary precision modulo is very complex whereas arbitrary precision bit tests are not.  Because of this insight I always prefer ( n & 1 ) since I know what is going on behind the scenes.  Sure, you can say that a smart compiler might optimize ( n % 2 ) to the same instruction set as ( n & 1 ) but what you really mean is "I'm doing it wrong by using % and hoping my compiler is smarter than I am."  Disregard the comments that ( n % 2 ) is easier to understand.  Turns out ( n & 1 ) is pretty easy to understand too (well, maybe not for my grandmother).  Use &, it's the right way.

Comment: I suppose you always write multiplications by powers of two with a bit shift.

Comment: Lol, let's not go overboard.  In that situation I nearly always multiply because like you I advocate clear intent over making micro optimizations where they usually aren't needed.  In this specific case though, (n&1) is the correct idiom to use to test for (odd|even)ness.  Not only is it faster, it's always clear since you'd never use the construct for anything else (i.e. if you treat n as a flags field then as a good programmer you'd use a named bitmask constant instead of 1).

Comment: Too bad it's not portable though.

Comment: Lol, not portable to what?  Every modern OS uses two's-complement integer representation and n&1 to test for evenness works just fine for positive and negative integers.  If you're planning a port to some 1980's one's-complement hack hardware that didn't sell but a few units then by all means worry about portability.

Comment: One thing you loose with (n & 1) is the intention. You should write what you want your code to do and rely on the compiler to handle it correctly. This seems like a low level premature optimisation that sacrifices code maintainability.